# C# SDK's for IIS

Tags: c#

Does anybody know all the SDK's needed for IIS6.0 development and the download links?  I keep finding this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525041%28v=vs.90%29.aspx but no link to download the actual SDK.  Visual Studio 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# IIS Windows 7 ComException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499691/c-iis-windows-7-comexception)

Comment: Marking this as a dupe because it is the exact same problem.  Mike: try to keep it in one question.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing to download.  You use the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Here's an example: http://www.codersource.net/asp-net/asp-net-advanced/iis-metabase-and-programmatic-administration-in-c.aspx

**UPDATE**
I've never heard of an "IIS Developer toolset".  I don't think such a thing exists.

However, they might be referring to the IIS 6 Configuration tools.  The screen shot shows what the options look like for IIS 7.  Just go into the add/remove windows features on the windows server and install the IIS admin tools.

[image]

Comment: I'm having an exception thrown that's because of an IIS developer toolset not being install client side, i was hoping someone might know.

Comment: There is an IIS SDK, which is part of the Windows SDK, formerly known as the Platform SDK.  I don't know if this is what you're talking about.